# Xamarin.Forms x:Name isn't linking my picker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xaml, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and XAML, and I'm currently trying to build an App by watching guides.

I'm trying to load a Picker with a list, I name it in the MainPage.xaml, but when I try to call it in the MainPage.xaml.cs it just doesn't exist.

Here's the code where I name the picker:

```
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="CDVAPP1.MainPage">


    <StackLayout>
        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>          
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Picker x:Name="clasePicker" Title="Selecciona una Raza" Grid.Row="0"/>

        </Grid>

    </StackLayout>


</ContentPage>
```

And here's when I try to call it:

```
namespace CDVAPP1
{

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
            loadClasePicker();
        }

        private void loadClasePicker()
        {

            var lista = new List<string>();
            lista.Add("Hello");
            lista.Add("Hi");
            lista.Add("Goodbye");
            clasePicker.ItemSource = lista;  (<<< here I can't select 'clasePicker' because it doesn't 
                                               even appear, 
                                               but that's the code I wanna use)
        }
```

Any help?

Comment: there is not an element named "clasePicker" in your XAML.  There is one named "razaPicker"

Comment: it was my bad. Edited. This is the original code.

Comment: Stop visual studio, delete the bin/obj folders, restart VS and rebuild

Comment: Thanks! It worked